# Editing sudoers file not taking effect

Tags: php, linux, rights, sudoers

Hey fellow programmers,

I'm working on my bachelor's project and got into a bit of a problem.

The goal is to create a web app, that can operate and modify I/O of a WAGO PLC 750-8202 (you can imagine it as some kind of industrial Raspberry PI) running an embedded linux with a lighttpd web server. I've made some C scripts that utilize DAL(HAL) functions the PLC provides.

Now I want to link it with my web application/site. I have a simple PHP page (ignore the button, it does nothing):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <button value="CLICK ME">CLICK ME</button>
<?php
echo system("kbusdemo1");
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

The kbusdemo1 executes but doesn't use the functions provided by DAL properly, it gives me an error. If I run that script as a root, it works perfectly. I found out that the problem lies with www user rights (that my web server lighttpd uses), so I tried editing sudoers with

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

Visudo is not implemented in the PLC linux system so I had to open it directly. I changed it to the code posted below, but if I try to run the C script as lighttpd user (with su www), it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for you suggestions.

```
# sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
#

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# Defaults specification

# Runas alias specification

# User privilege specification 
root  ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL 
admin ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/config-tools/get_user_info user 
ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/config-tools/get_user_info 
www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# Uncomment to allow people in group wheel to run all commands
# and set environment variables.
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL) SETENV: ALL

# Same thing without a password
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SETENV: ALL

# Samples
# %users  ALL=/sbin/mount /cdrom,/sbin/umount /cdrom
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Comment: I think the problem you need to look at is why does `kbusdemo1` run only when run  as root. Does it read any files which are (unnecessarily) owned by root. Did you compiler `kbusdemo1` as root ? (unnecessarily again?) Or the hard ware interaction you have written needs root privileges?

Comment: It might be the case that the harware interaction needs root privileges. It needs to access inner memory of the PLC, get info about values of I/O modules and change them, so I think the scripts are required to run as root.

Comment: Okay, so now instead of trying to add the binary to the sudoers file, you can change the owner of file to `root` and try to set the `suid` flag for the binary. This will let any user to run the binary as root.

Comment: You can `chown` to change ownerof the binary to root. Then switch to root and run `chmod u+s kbusdemo1`.

Comment: PHP, `system` and `sudo` are the ingredients to cook wonderful security holes. You should take a look [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html) to learn a bit about the security problems.

Comment: BTW if you still want to use the sudoers file, you have to still add sudo before the command. It just wont prompt for the password. so you will have to do `system("sudo ...")`

Comment: `www ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` -- This is very risky. Do it just for your file not ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help. I got it working, I wasn't calling the script as sudo from the PHP file. And as you suggested, I changed the lines in sudoers to only allow that one particular script, so no security holes for me.